# document.body.getElementById and document.getElementById difference

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning javascript from scratch. I am currently trying to grasp DOM.
I have a HTML page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to javascript</h1>

    Visit me <a href="facebook.com">here.</a>

    <p> <img id="image" src="kalam.jpg"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to read `a` tags.

```
var links = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]; 

console.log(links.href);
```

It works fine. Now I want to read image.

```
var imageLink = document.body.getElementById("image");

console.log(imageLink.src);
```

But, the above code is not working.

I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.body.getElementById is not a function.

Changing it to:

```
var imageLink = document.getElementById("image");

console.log(imageLink.src);
```

works fine.

My question is about the difference between `document.body.getEl...` and `document.getEl..`?

Does `document.body` reads only body part while `document.getEl..` reads whole document including titles etc? If is it so then should not both the above code working?

Comment: `document.body` doesn't have `getElementById`.

Comment: `document.body.getElementById` does not exist as code - not sure where you got that from

Comment: The term "not working" is far too vague to be useful; if you're going to use it again on SO make sure it's accompanied with a follow up explanation of what that actually means. Does it result in an error/exception being thrown? Does it give the wrong result?

Comment: read this first -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document than -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I have edited my question. Have a look please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` gets the element with the matching ID from the document.

`document.body.getElementById()` does not exist.

`document.getElementsByTagName()` gets all the elements which match the tag name from the document.

`someOtherElement.getElementsByTagName` gets all the elements which match the tag name and which are descendants of `someOtherElement`.

Since an ID must be globally unique within an HTML document, there is generally no need for the `getElementById` method to exist anywhere other than on the `document` object itself.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. I was not getting it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**getElementById** is a function of document object (so it simply doesn't exist in *document.body*)

**getElementsByTagName** is a function of any dom element (including *document.body*).

Answer (score 0):

Using document.getElementById you are retrieving a specific element with the specified ID on the page. IDs should be unique to each element on a page. when using document.form (or whatever) you are 'filtering down' your selection.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're new to this it might be worth using

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')[0]
document.querySelector('#image')
document.querySelector('.someclass')
```

just because it does tag, id and class all in one.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am reading http://eloquentjavascript.net/. Please provide me other links too.